# Preload / cache images with URLs responding HTTP-redirects

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, http-redirect, preload

I'd like to make the browser preload / cache images so they load more quickly. Usually this is done as follows:

```
var URL = "http://example.com/image.jpg";
var image = new Image();
image.src = URL;
```

But in my case, the URL responds a HTTP-redirect which approximately looks like this:

```
$ curl -i "http://example.com/image.jpg"
HTTP/2 302
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: http://example.com/resolved.jpg
content-length: 0
```

Is it possible that that's the reason why preloading / caching doesn't work? (I successfully tested my code with the resolved URLs in place of the original URLs and the preloading / caching worked fine.)

Answer (score 3):

You can preload images as blobs and then use blob URLs. You can use XHR request (you can use xhr.responseURL to to load blob) or fetch API (polyfill is available).

```
let convertUrlToImage = (url) => {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => {
      if (response.redirected) {
        console.log(`redirected to [${response.url}]`)
      } 
      return response.blob();
    }).then((imageBlob) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
        image.onload = function() {
            resolve(image)
        }
      });
    });
}

let images = ["flor.jpg", "animal.jpg", "human.jpg"];
let imagesPromises  = images.map(convertUrlToImage);
Promise.all(imagesPromises).then((images) => {
    //do whatever with images: Image[];
});
```

You can configure fetch to follow or not follow redirects see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here is wrong. The subsequent content response is cacheable (if served with appropriate headers) but the initial 302 response is most definitely not. And most of your performance costs are in latency of round trips to the srrver. While you could return a 301, I would **strongly** advise against this. It's very, very rarely right to use a 301. The right solution is to make a 200 response on the first request.